# Is there something like Trixbox CE for Ubuntu Server?

Tags: voip, landscape

In an effort to keep things consistent, I've been slowly but surely replacing CentOS and *BSD servers with Ubuntu Lucid. I've come across a few that I'll have problems migrating, in particular several Trixbox CE servers that are based on CentOS.

We'd like to bring everything we have under one management roof, either by using Landscape or something similar that we nail together in house.

Is there something like Trixbox that will work on Ubuntu? Either Asterisk or Freeswitch, preferably pre-packaged by a vendor in .deb format? I dug through Launchpad PPA's in hopes of finding a port of either, but I did not find anything.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As trixbox is open source, it should be possible to port the management interface to Ubuntu?

Or [FreePBX](http://www.freepbx.org/) (I think Trixbox actually uses the FreePBX admin tools).

Seems like [FreePBX installation page mentions Ubuntu](http://www.freepbx.org/support/documentation/installation).  (There is also more to be found on Google...)

[FreePBX also works with FreeSwitch](http://nicegear.co.nz/blog/freeswitch-and-freepbx-v3-running-on-ubuntu-on-an-alix-board/) on an embeded system with Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 2):

You can try **Asterisk** or **Sipwitch** that you can find in repository. If you want GUI, you can use **gastman** (GUI tool for Asterisk administration and monitoring).

Comment: I was really hoping for an intuitive GUI to help manage it, vs configuring Asterisk by hand

Comment: You can use "gastman" (GUI tool for Asterisk administration and monitoring). You can find it in Lucid repository.

Comment: yevhene, can you add your gastman recommendation to your answer so it shows up there?

Answer (score 1):

Elastix is another Asterisk based PBX that works 100% on Ubuntu, have several CPUs running it and make PBX servers with Elastix on Ubuntu.  Main reason is the CentOS versions will not allow updating, but the one's that work on Ubuntu do.

OMR